# how to display a list in c#

Tags: c#, youtube.net-api

I would like to make an app that resembles winamp but has an youtube data input ( i.e. in stead of local music i have a multitude of links from which i stream music ) . I would like to know how to display the list? should i have an UserControl for each link or is there another way ? i was also thinking of storing the links in a dataTable and on quit saving it to a local database/file . Is that the way to go? If you have any suggestions i am looking forward to hearing them!

Regards,
Alexandru Badescu

Comment: i was going to do it in winforms anyway but i am interested in the display of the list : should i define a userControl for every link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I would be best to create a user control for each url, and put all the user controls into a scrollable container.

If all users must specify the link to the file, I would save each playlist as a (simple) file, where each line contains one link.